# Найти точку слияния списков

Tags: c++, алгоритм

В [задаче](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/find-the-merge-point-of-two-joined-linked-lists/submissions/code/18073914) нужно найти точку слияния односвязных списков и вывести значение в этой ноде. Я сделал очень просто: если списки разной длины, вычисляю разность их длин, это количество лишних элементов. Пропускаю лишние элементы и начинаю одновременно двигаться по двум спискам, пока не найдется общая точка.

Можно ли решить задачу с помощью инвертирования списков? Я на бумажке порисовал различные варианты инвертирования одного списка или двух сразу, рассматривал вариант прохода с конца, но в голову ничего не пришло.

Нет ли в моем коде сегфолтов?

```
/*
   Find merge point of two linked lists
   Node is defined as
   struct Node
   {
       int data;
       Node* next;
   }
*/

// Подсчет количества элементов в списке
int count(Node *head)
{
    int c = 0;
    while(head)
    {
        c++;
        head = head->next;
    }
    return c;
}
int FindMergeNode(Node *headA, Node *headB)
{
    if(headA && headB)  // Если один из списков не пуст
    {
        int len_a = count(headA);    // Вычисление длин списков A и B
        int len_b = count(headB);
        int diff = std::abs(len_a - len_b); // Разность между длинами списков
        for(int i = 0; i < diff; i++) // Пропуск лишних элементов в самом длинном списке
            (len_a > len_b) ? headA = headA->next : headB = headB->next;
        while(headA != NULL && headB != NULL)
        {
            if(headA == headB) // Если найдена точка слияния (адреса нод равны)
                return headA->data;
            headA = headA->next;
            headB = headB->next;
        }
    }
    return 0xDEADBEEF;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Опишите саму *задачу* в вопросе *русскими словами*. Не заставляйте бегать по ссылкам.

Comment: Задача: два списка сливаются в некоторой точке. Надо найти эту точку. Добавил пример в пост.

Comment: Не зря Вас кто-то минусует. После описания задачи изложите до кода (русскими словами) его краткий алгоритм (идею и лежащие в его основе предположения о содержимом списков) и откомментируйте код.

Comment: @avp, словесного описания алгоритма, начиная со второго предложения, вполне достаточно. Коменты добавил.

Comment: @Abyx он вынужден использовать данную функцию. Это не его вина. Такова постановка задачи. В эту функцию передаются данные из системы.

Comment: @Abyx, эти задачи на алгоритмы и структуры данных. Скорее всего, автор в самом деле не может в кресты, но нужно было предложить выбор разных языков.

Comment: @typemoon, из Вашего описания (без изучения кода) абсолютно не ясно, что подразумевается под *точкой слияния* списков. То ли, начиная с некоторого элемента, оба списка на самом деле одни и те же **адреса структур в памяти** (именно это и подразумевается?), то ли у них *одинаковые значения поля data*. Видимо в этом и  основная причина низкого качества Вашего вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

В чем смысл вопроса, если задача решена? Hackerrank предоставляет testcase's. Раз она их проходит, то чего Вы еще хотите? Если Вы решаете там задачи, то должны знать, что если сегфолт будет принципиален в ней (задаче) и Вы с ним попробуете пройти testcase's, то получите соответствующее сообщение. Также, если задача будет по времени слишком долго решаться, то тоже не пройдете testcase's пока не оптимизируете ее. Зачем Вы зациклились на тривиальной задаче с простым уровнем сложности. Решили - идите дальше. Там Вас ждут гораздо более интересные вещи.

Comment: Хочется решить ее нетривиальным способом. И я правда зацикливаюсь на многих вещах, не знаю, почему так происходит, но возникает сильное желание сделать что-нибудь еще или изучить что-то глубже, даже если в полученных знаниях не будет смысла.

Comment: @typemoon Поверьте, будут Вам там интересные вещи в достатке. Посидите Вы еще и пораскинете мозгами над некоторыми задачами не одни сутки. А изобретать колесо не имеет смысла. Изобретите хотя бы велосипед :)